# How to know my code is running on CPU or GPU?

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, gpu, openacc

I am a  beginner in OpenACC. I want to speed up my program by using OpenACC in fortran language with GCC compiler. my Code is :

```
Program Test

 use openacc

 Implicit None
  integer(8)::I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I,ii,jj,J

    !$acc kernels
    !$acc loop
     do I=1,1200000000
     do II=1,300
     do jj=1,200
     do I1=1,200
    do I2=1,500
     if(I2==20.and.I1==200.and.JJ==200.and.II==200)then
     print*,"Hello"
     endif
      Data1(I)=I-I+I-I+I
      enddo
      enddo
       enddo
        enddo
         enddo

          !$acc end kernels
            end
```

speed of my code did not change.
  How can I know my code is running on CPU or GPU?or How I change my code to speed up my program?

Comment: If that's your real code then the reason the speed didn't change may be that printing `Hello` a gazillion times is essentially a serial operation (and relatively slow too).  No matter how fast your CPU / GPU process the innermost statements, your output sub-system will plod along at the same pace regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to know code is running on host or target device.
The solution is to use acc_on_device (acc_device_host)) function. If code is running on host this function return true and if code is running on target device this function return False.
My code is running on host(CPU).But another question is why this code does not run on target device(GPU)?

Comment: What compiler are you using? After adding a declaration for Data1 to the code and an `independent` to your `!$acc loop` I was able to get the PGI compiler to build it for the GPU. Also, do you mean to have such a large trip count?

Comment: I  am using GCC compiler  and AMD GPU

Answer (score 0):

You could also monitor your job with nvidia-smi command (if using NVidia GPU).

Maybe something linked to Offloading compilation options ? https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading#Compilation_options